# Logging in user cross domain using AJAX (rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am having an issue where I have a web app that has a www for landing pages and information and it has an "app.application.io". I am allowing the user to create an account on a www. page then they need to put in their credit card information on the same page. The problem is that i cannot log them in without redirecting to the "app." domain.

Here is my code:

```
#Create account
def create

  dont_redirect = params[:dont_redirect]
  organization_name = params[:organization_name]

  organization_prefix = organization_name.gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase

  #Check if there's an organization with this source email already
  existing_organizations = Organization.active
                                       .select("1")
                                       .where("source_email like '%#{organization_prefix}%'")

  #If we do have an organization then append a number to the end
  organization_prefix = organization_prefix + existing_organizations.count.to_s if existing_organizations && existing_organizations.count > 0

  source_email =  organization_prefix + '@contactflowmail.com'

  organization = Organization.create!(name: organization_name, source_email: source_email, billing_plan_id: 1,
    subscription_ends_at: Time.now + 14.days)

  user = User.new(user_params)
  user.organization = organization
  user.role = 'owner'
  user.source = params[:source]

#Creates the account for the user and signs them in if it is successful
  if user.save
    sign_in(user)
    #Add contact to Contact Flow Contact Flow account
    ContactFlow.addContact(user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email, 'cf-trial')
    if dont_redirect 
       render json: {success: true, organization_id: user.organization_id}
    else
      redirect_to ENV['APP_ROOT_PATH'] + "/onboarding" 
    end
  else
    render json: {success: false, message: user.errors.full_messages.join("<br />")}
  end
end
```

If you have any questions please ask.